# Route Class Undefined

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.7, and the following error ocurrs with this code:+

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/welcome', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Route' not found in C:\wamp64\www\master-fullstack\api-rest-laravel\routes\web.php:14

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Route' not found in C:\wamp64\www\master-fullstack\api-rest-laravel\routes\api.php on line 16

Comment: The problem isn't in this file/code you've mentioned. It seems something is wrong with your API routes, on routes\api.php

Comment: Also getting this error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Route' not found in C:\wamp64\www\master-fullstack\api-rest-laravel\routes\web.php:14

Comment: Check if you have this code in your app.php, inside 'aliases': 'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class

Comment: Can´t find app.php

Comment: It's inside config folder

Comment: 'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class, found it.

Comment: Running app.php. I got this error:Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function env()

Comment: Then, I think something is wrong with your Laravel installation. Try clearing the config cache. If it doesn't work, install Laravel again.